# contents not being added to the Fitnesse test/suite

Tags: rest, fitnesse

I am trying to create new test page from REST api calls in Fitnesse. The page is being created but the contents is not being added.

I am using addChild responder.

here is my code.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet post = new HttpGet("http://localhost:80/TestSuite?responder=addChild&pageName=RestSuite&pageType=Suite&content=valuetosave");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    String str1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println(str1);
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find any examples also.. please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of efforts I found that that [documentation is wrong for Rest on fitness.org](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.RestfulServices) the parameter in the request is not 'content' but 'pageContent'...

Comment: Is there anyway to send content as the body of a post request. I am trying to create a page and &content=... has illegal characters in it.